# Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? Entity framework Distinct Function

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have requirement in which i just want to return List of Unique Vendor ID based on Service Status, Done/No;

```
Select Distinct(vendorid) FROM DC_System_Assets where ServiceStatus='Done'
```

I tried to write like that but it's getting error.

```
public List<int> AutoScheduleMails()
{
    var v = db.DC_System_Assets.Select(f => f.VendorId).Distinct().Where(p => p.ServiceStatus == "Done").ToList();
}
```

> 'System.Nullable' does not contain a definition for
>   'ServiceStatus' and no extension method 'ServiceStatus' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'System.Nullable' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting a list of `VendorId`s, and then trying to filter by `ServiceStatus` (which is not a property of `VendorId`). Try...

```
var v = db.DC_System_Assets
            .Where(a => a.ServiceStatus == "Done")
            .Select(a => a.VendorId)
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();
```

Comment: thanks sir, but how can i return it through function List<Dc_System_Assets> or List<int>.... in both cases showing erorr

Comment: Change your return type to `List<int?>`. `VendorId` is a nullable int (`int?`).

Comment: Bundle of thanks sir, i was really feeling headache since yesterday :)  Its working fine now